# Data Pre-Fetching and State | Vue SSR Guide

Tags: vue.js

Can you tell me what is the usage of created inside the data vue?

```js
created() {
    if (this.$store.state.auth.loggedIn) {
        if ((this.usersId = this.$store.state.auth.user.results.userId)) {
            this.owner = true;
        }
    }
    UserService.getDiscussionDetail(this.$route.params.id).then(
        (response) => {
            this.discussion = response;
        },
        () => {
            this.success = false;
        }
    );
},
```

Comment: `https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-component-lifecycle#:~:text=Introduction,DOM%2C%20updated%2C%20or%20destroyed.` please check this. you can understand vue hooks.

Answer (score 0):

The created hook runs when the Vue instance is created, just before the virtual DOM nodes are available. This is usually the step where async operations in server side generated apps are processed, such as fetching content and other data that have to be included in the finished DOM tree in the hte static output. The steps in a Vue Lifecycle. are: beforeCreate, created, beforeMount, mounted, beforeUpdate, updated, beforeDestroy, and destroyed.